# Append Data to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 7], 'B': [4, 5, 6, 29]})
```

I'm working on a for loop that grabs an index and then appends data to the end of that row.

How do I append columns `C`, `D`, `E` for a given index of the table? Let's say on iteration one, the index is 2:

```
    A    B    C    D   E
0   1    4    0    0   0
1   2    5    0    0   0
2   3    6    34   12  23
3   7    29   0    0   0
```

On the next iteration of the for loop, the index might be 1. Then the dataframe would be:

```
    A    B    C    D   E
0   1    4    0    0   0
1   2    5    8    11  4
2   3    6    34   12  23
3   7    29   0    0   0
```

How do I do this?

Comment: whats the logic the increment of numbers?

Comment: Is it important to add rows incrementally? So I'm guessing you don't want to use `df.join`?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. You haven't even provided the data in a convenient format.

Answer (score 2):

You can target specific rows by using loc and providing the index.

For example:

```
df.loc[5:'D']=10
```

This will add the value 10, to the column D of row index 5.

Your question states that you want to add new columns depending on the row index. This doesn't make sense, because a dataframe is not like a NoSQL document where you can just add columns independent of other rows.

What you should do is have all your columns already added to your dataframe, then add values as you go.

To add multiple values:

```
df.loc[5, ['D', 'B']] = 10
```